# tee to a compressed file

Tags: shell, unix, tee, compression

tee reads from standard input and writes to standard output and a file.

```
some_command |& tee log
```

Is that possible for tee to write to a compressed file?

```
some_command |& tee -some_option log.bz2
```

If tee can not do that, is there any other command?

I can redirect the output to a compressed file with

```
some_command |& bzip2 > log.bz2
```

But with this command, the output to standard output is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're OK having your output on stderr, you can redirect it:

```
some_command | tee /dev/stderr | bzip2 > log.bz2
```

This tees the output to both stdout and stderr (`| tee /dev/stderr`). Then it pipes the stdout to bzip2 (`| bzip2 > log.bz2`)

Comment: This will have the same problem as gzip: in the event of a system crash, you will have an empty output log file `log.bz2`

Answer (score 14):

If your shell is `bash` (version 4.x), you have ['process substitution'](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), and you could use:

```
some_command 2>&1 | tee >(bzip2 -c > log.bz2)
```

This redirects standard error and standard output to `tee` (like `|&` does, but I prefer the classic notation). The copy of `tee`'s output is sent to a process instead of a file; the process is `bzip2 -c > log.bz2` which writes its standard input in compressed format to its standard output.  The other (uncompressed) copy of the output goes direct to standard output, of course.